# Retrieving app messages

Tags: applications, home-screen

Is there a way to (offline)  retrieve app messages (messages that  appear with on the top right on the home screen with a small icon of the app)

Without opening the app itself? (or when the app doesn't store these messages)

Or is there an app that I can install that can remember these messages?

I am using a Dtek 50 android 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Notification History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) records  notifications, toasts, Dialog message and many more.

You can configure it store these either for 30 days or 300 Notifications and view off line

From app description:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>(click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Android still (far as I know until 8) has an internal notification log. You have to access it via Nova Launcher / Activities / Settings / Notification Log. I've detailed this in a post below.

Answer (score 1):

Use Nova Launcher, then once installed, add a "widget" to your Nova Launcher home screen for the "Notification Log". Proof this is possible on Android 8 Oreo:

[image: Notification Log from Nova Launcher]

1. Install Nova Launcher and run it
2. Long press on your Nova Launcher home screen
3. Press and hold to add an **ACTIVITIES** widget (should be near the top)
4. From there choose a Settings widget
5. Choose Notification Log
6. Select your new Notification Log to access the Android Notification Log.

I don't know why Google hid the notification log widget and judging from the huge number of apps in the Play store that offer to record notifications for you, it really is a sought after feature. Thanks to Nova Launcher for making such a great app!

Originally seen in a comment from Javier P [on this page](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s8-and-s8-plus/893346-can-i-retrieve-cleared-notifications.html). May the gods bless his life.

Comment: +1. At the time of posting my answer, I wasn't aware of this and later saw that it works on Pie too. Good to have alternatives for users