# How to stop ads for turning on Google Assistant?

Tags: notifications, google-assistant

I'm not sure what's changed but the past week or two I've been getting notification ads for Google assistant every day, very annoying. They take the format of 'why not call a friend?' 'Want a joke? ' - Turn assistant on! That kind of utterly valueless nonsense.

I believe these come from the Google app, but here's the thing:

1. Google App notifications are OFF
2. I cannot remove or disable the Google App

How do I stop these daily ads I didn't consent to? I've hunted and there is nothing in the settings anywhere allowing this.

Comment: Thanks but the feed is already turned off, along with all notifications

Comment: It may not be from assistant at all - please install app mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/179785/131553) and track from which app those things are emanating

Answer (score 0):

Turns out turning off auto-update on the Play Store has fixed it. No idea why or how, very unexpected - but it's done it!

I'd be interested to hear if anyone else with this issue can resolve it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: The question isn't super specific on that in contrary to its title, so I'll assume that you have **Assistant turned off** or **don't want it**. I don't think there would be ads otherwise*.

---

[OP's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/182152) stated that turning off auto-update on the Play Store fixed his issue, which seems very random and probably unrelated to me. There's a sure way to disable these notifications though, and it's starting to be a known trick for people who don't want Google Assistant at all :

By **changing your device's language to a less known regional variant of it**, you'll make Google think that Assistant isn't available for you and your country, thus **preventing it to be offered to you anymore** by those "ads" or by long home button press.

For example, if you live in the U.S, and speak English, your device's primary language probably is ***"English (United States)"***. Changing it to ***"English (U.S Virgin Islands)"***  will make any mentions of Google Assistant disappear from your phone. In my case, my device's language is French (France), so I changed it to French (Swiss) to get rid of Assistant.

Keep in mind: Assistant may someday be available to all English countries so this solution isn't completely future-proof.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, hopefully it's helpful to someone! I agree about the randomness of my solution, but it was actually after following advice is read elsewhere. Must be an odd connection between the play store and the Google standard apps; maybe even a bug

Comment: Hiya, I noticed that you were unable to post images on here due to low rep. However, you could mention the links in the comments here, then other users can incorporate them into the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was not the annoying notifications — I just turned off Google Assistant. (In the Google app: Settings > Google Assistant > Assistant > Phone) The problem was that it keeps begging you to turn it back on. But anyway, the method of getting rid of Google is the same:

Uninstalling all updates for the Google app by clicking "uninstall" in the Play Store (rolling back to the version that comes with the system) and turning off auto-updates for it in Google Play seems to help.

But it sure has its problems. Sooner or later, the newest version of the Google app will ship with all phones, and rolling back won't help.

And then, you will just have to search how to uninstall apps with ADB/Fastboot and just uninstall the Google app altogether, if you're comfortable doing that. There is a utility for Xiaomi phones called "Xiaomi ADB/Fastboot Tools". It can remove any app and requires no root, but you will need to enable USB debugging. Even if it doesn't work for non-Xiaomi phones straight away, I'm pretty sure it can be made to work with them, or you can just use the command line to do the same things.

I am sure that removing Google isn't harmful to your device in any way. If you're addicted to Google search, you can just use Chrome's search bar widget. And it seems that Google's two-factor authentication for your account is a system-integrated thingie that doesn't depend on the Google app at all. But nevertheless, if you're going to remove the Google app from your phone, I DO NOT guarantee that you won't brick your phone and/or two-factor authentication by doing so, and you should do your own research. It's pretty unlikely that you'll brick it, though.