# How do I prevent notifications from certain app from being dismissed?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar

So, going on the opposite side of the maiority of people: there are apps whose notifications **I don't want to be able do dismiss**.

For example, I use Samsung Health and Daylio to keep track of my sleeping habits and my moods and activities, and they both give me notifications for when to go open the app to record something.

As a reflex of my body, what happens is, I open the notification bar and click the *Clear All* on instinct, resulting in me forgetting to open it later to make that record.

Reminder apps are simply not working with me.

Is there any way I can configure notifications for being undismissable? I wanted them to clear only if I clicked them, or if I did the thing it was expecting me to do.

**Device Information:**

- Model# SM-G950FD (Galaxy S8 flat)
- Android 7.0

Comment: [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dvdh.notiflog) claims to store notifications so that you can read them later . Another app I use is in this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/179785/131553). Your ask of *preventing dismissal* would  need root as you are attempting to change system behaviour (if such a solution exists)

Comment: If the notifications you get can be *guessed* by you even after accidental deletion, you can think of automation that prompts you that you had a notification from xyz app and that notification stays till you physically clear it. In addition that Notification from automation app can be clicked to to launch xyz app. If you want to check wait the notification was (in case you can't guess) you can see from one of the apps mentioned above. Lot of work but then it can't be helped